# Windows Store App - All UI elements lose their visual representation, Windows restart does not solve

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

After leaving my app on a Windows tablet and getting back to it in a day, its whole interface is broken - all visual elements are missing, but still somewhat working. Also restarting Windows does not fix the problem, the only think that works is uninstalling and installing again.

[image: Broken UI]

This is how it looks when it's ok:
[image: This is how it looks when it's ok]

This is happening on Windows 8, 8.1 and 10. The device I have seen it on is Samsung 500T tablet, both installed from the store and with Remote Debugger.
I have catched this bug few time and it's been repored few more, but I'm not even sure how to begin to debug it. Have anyone seen the samething like this?

Comment: Start by isolating the issue. Does this happen on multiple apps or just some/one? If not all then what's different about those where this happens? Can you recreate with a simple app? Does it happen on just one device or others too?

Comment: I have not seen it happen with any other app, just mine. This happen too rare, so I can't reliably replicate it. Once it happens it stays that way and can only be fixed with re-installing the app. I think it had happened on other devices, but i'm not entirely sure - this bug haunts us for quite some time.

Comment: Have you used some async method for example reading files, or getting responses from webservice? After you accessed these data, did you take a  method to dispose them?